# Dúvida sobre tabela HTML

Tags: html, css

Estou a realizar um pequeno trabalho, que contém uma tabela como mostro na imagem, infelizmente não estou a conseguir realizar com este código:

```
<table border = 1>
    <tr>
      <td> Cliente </td>
      <td>         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Estado do Processo </td>
      <td>                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Nº Encomenda </td>
      <td>              </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Interveniente </td>
      <td>               </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Entre Datas </td>
    <td>         </td>
    </tr>
  <table>
```

Ou seja a minha ideia era fazer uma tabela com 2 células em cada linha, sendo a 2º célula de cada linha completamente vazia.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef1x8.png]
Desculpem se é algo simples, mas estou iniciando a linguagem.
Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Para mim, a segunda coluna da tabela ficou vazia, como esperado. Não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss  Acho que ele quer por uma borda ao redor de cada cedula da primeira coluna

Comment: Mas já está assim... dê mais detalhes e explique o problema ou o que não está ficando como vc gostaria

Comment: Oi, a última tag <table>, deve fechá-la, assim </table>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade a segunda coluna está vazia, mas como não tem uma largura definida, ela fica sem tamanho.

Você pode definir um `width` no CSS para as segundas células de cada linha, por exemplo, `200px`, usando a pseudo-classe `:nth-child(2)`. O valor `2` representa o segundo elemento filho ([mais sobre nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)):

```css
table tr td:nth-child(2){
   width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table border = 1>
    <tr>
      <td> Cliente </td>
      <td>         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Estado do Processo </td>
      <td>                    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Nº Encomenda </td>
      <td>              </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Interveniente </td>
      <td>               </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Entre Datas </td>
    <td>         </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

> Obs. nos comentários: a tabela deve ser fechada com a tag `</table>`.

Comment: desculpe-me a intromissão, mas explicar os pseudo css não seria legal? Visto que deixou apenas a solução sem referência? Aparentemente o usuário é base.

Comment: Tranquilo! Coloquei uma explicação na resposta. ObG!